# What is the invisible mass in the universe?

Tags: astrophysics

According to scientists, currently the edge of observable universe from the earth is about 14 billion parsec. This means that the diameter of the universe is nearly 91 billion light years. If we consider all the matter we could see, some say it only makes 4 percent of the matter calculated from the density. What is the universe lacking in such a case. Also which massive things are there which can be observed but not directly seen?

Comment: The missing "mass" is dark matter and dark energy. The "size" of the universe is not a simple concept. One can't take a 91 billion lightyear long ruler, lay it out and get from one end to the other.

Comment: @CuriousOne it is dark matter not dark energy.. i think OP is using Newtonian mechanics and so dark energy cannot be included..

Comment: @BruceLee: The OP is simply quoting numbers he has heard. If one talks about the mass of the universe and the visible mass is 4% (4.9% to be more precise, I believe), then dark energy has to be included. That his mental model is insufficient to make sense of what these numbers mean is OK, we are here to help him with that.

Comment: @CuriousOne the imprecision of OP's numbers then saves your day... :P

Comment: @BruceLee: Not at all... if you just take the ratio between matter and dark matter, then it should be more along the 18%. I don't think the OP mistook 4 for 18.

Comment: yeeah bruce lee is right when it comes about numericals.but where I do really get confused is with this dark matter and dark energy.how can I even know or measure something which I cannot even see or feel like

Comment: Why do you assume that dark matter and dark energy can not be "seen" or "felt"? Dark matter causes very significant gravitational effects (larger than ordinary matter) and dark energy changes the global structure of the universe, which is visible to astronomers. Neither dark matter nor dark energy are subtle phenomena. They are what drives the overall structure of the universe. Ordinary matter basically just follows them.

Comment: The question of what dark matter and energy actually are is up to speculation. It is however certain that it does not interact or hardly interacts with EM force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invisible mass in the universe as you mentioned refers to mass which is not visible using electromagnetic radiation. It is called dark matter and was detected by the virtue of its gravitational effects. The diameter of the universe doesn't play much role in your question.

Secondly, there can be many massive things which can't be seen by EM radiation but can be detected otherwise. Precise details are needed to exactly point out such things.

Comment: thank you all so much . you helped me understand the basics